# How get Total Price ADD and REMOVE items in Cart Page using Redux and React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to get total price of items added and removed in Cart, but total just increase and no decrease when remove one item.

I'm working with reducer and I am almost sure that I've implemented here the logic but I'm very stuck in this trouble.

This is my code reducer in CartRedux.js

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    products: [],
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.products.push((product) => product._id === action.payload);
      state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
    clearCart: (state) => {
      state.products = [];
    },
    deleteProductStart: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.error = false;
    },
    deleteProductSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.quantity -= 1;
      state.products.splice(
        state.products.findIndex((item) => item._id === action.payload),
        1
      );
      //agregar aquí la función para restar el total en el RESUMEN DE COMPRA
    },
    deleteProductFailure: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deleteProductSuccess` case reducer isn't computing/recomputing a total, but instead is only adjusting the total quantity.

Both `quantity` and `total` are what would be considered *derived* "state", meaning these are easily computed values from *actual* state, and don't generally belong as part of the state as it's considered a React anti-pattern. The suggestion here is to instead store ***just*** the `products` array and compute the derived state the `cart.products` array.

Example:

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    products: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.products.find((product) => product._id === action.payload.id);

      if (item) {
        item.quantity += action.payload.quantity;
      } else {
        state.products.push(action.payload);
      }
    },
    clearCart: (state) => {
      state.products = [];
    },
    deleteProductStart: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.error = false;
    },
    deleteProductSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.products.splice(
        state.products.findIndex((item) => item._id === action.payload.id),
        1
      );
    },
    deleteProductFailure: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
  }
});

// Note: the selector functions need to access the correct state from root.
// This is dictated by how you combine reducers and structure the reducer tree.
// This is just an example since I've no idea what the overall state
// looks like, it assumes `cart` is a root reducer/state property.
export const cartQuantitySelector = (state) => state.cart.products.reduce(
  (quantity, item) => quantity + item.quantity,
  0
);
export const cartTotalSelector = (state) => state.cart.products.reduce(
  (total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity,
  0
);
```

Getting the cart quantity & cart total in component

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { cartQuantitySelector, cartTotalSelector } from '../path/to/CartRedux';

...

const cartQuantity = useSelector(cartQuantitySelector);
const cartTotal = useSelector(cartTotalSelector);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array filter method to remove a specific element from an array without mutating the original state.

```js
state.products = state.products.filter(element => element._id !== action.payload);
```

Alternatively you can use slice to remove elements from your state:

```js
state.products = [
    ...state.products.slice(0, action.payload),
    ...state.products.slice(action.payload + 1)
],
```

Also you are not decreasing your total value when you delete one item from your state.

```js
state.total -= action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
```

All in all your deleteProductSuccess function should look like:

```js
deleteProductSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.quantity -= 1;
      state.products = state.products.filter(element => element._id !== action.payload);
      state.total -= action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the code , as I did the same for mini project

store.js

```
        import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
        import cartReducer from "../features/cartSlice";
        
        export const store = configureStore({
          reducer: {
            allCart: cartReducer,
          },
        });
    
    
        Navbar.js
        import React, { useEffect } from "react";
        import {
          MDBContainer,
          MDBNavbar,
          MDBNavbarBrand,
          MDBBtn,
        } from "mdb-react-ui-kit";
        import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
        import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
        
        import { getCartTotal } from "../features/cartSlice";
        
        export default function App() {
          
          const { cart, totalQuantity } = useSelector((state) => state.allCart);
          const dispatch = useDispatch();
        
          useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(getCartTotal());
          }, [cart]);
        
          return (
            <MDBNavbar light bgColor="light">
              <MDBContainer fluid>
                <MDBNavbarBrand>Navbar</MDBNavbarBrand>
                <span>
                  <Link to="/">All Product </Link>
                </span>
                <MDBBtn color="light">
                  <Link to="/cart">Cart({totalQuantity})</Link>
                </MDBBtn>
              </MDBContainer>
            </MDBNavbar>
          );
        }

    cartSlice.js
    import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import productData from "../productData";
    
    const initialState = {
      cart: [],
      items: productData,
      totalQuantity: 0,
      totalPrice: 0,
    };
    
    const cartSlice = createSlice({
      name: "cart",
      initialState,
      reducers: {
        addToCart: (state, action) => {
          let find = state.cart.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
          if (find >= 0) {
            state.cart[find].quantity += 1;
          } else {
            state.cart.push(action.payload);
          }
        },
    
        getCartTotal: (state) => {
          let { totalQuantity, totalPrice } = state.cart.reduce((cartTotal, cartItem) => {
              const { price, quantity } = cartItem;
              const itemTotal = price * quantity;
              cartTotal.totalPrice += itemTotal;
              cartTotal.totalQuantity += quantity;
              return cartTotal;
            },
            {
              totalPrice: 0,
              totalQuantity: 0,
            }
          );
          state.totalPrice = parseInt(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
          state.totalQuantity = totalQuantity;
        },
    
        removeItem: (state, action) => {
          state.cart = state.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
        },
    
        increaseItemQuantity: (state, action) => {
          state.cart = state.cart.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === action.payload) {
              return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 };
            }
            return item;
          });
        },
        decreaseItemQuantity: (state, action) => {
          state.cart = state.cart.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === action.payload) {
              return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity - 1 };
            }
            return item;
          });
        },
      },
    });
    
    export const {
      addToCart,
      getCartTotal,
      removeItem,
      increaseItemQuantity,
      decreaseItemQuantity,
    } = cartSlice.actions;
    
    export default cartSlice.reducer;

    cartPage.js
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    
    import {
      getCartTotal,
      removeItem,
      decreaseItemQuantity,
      increaseItemQuantity,
    } from "../features/cartSlice";
    
    const CartPage = () => {
      const { cart, totalQuantity, totalPrice } = useSelector((state) => state.allCart );
    
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCartTotal());
      }, [cart]);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <section className="h-100 gradient-custom">
            <div className="container py-5">
              <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center my-4">
                <div className="col-md-8">
                  <div className="card mb-4">
                    <div className="card-header py-3">
                      <h5 className="mb-0">Cart - {cart.length} items</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                      {cart?.map((data) => (
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                            <div
                              className="bg-image hover-overlay hover-zoom ripple rounded"
                              data-mdb-ripple-color="light"
                            >
                              <img
                                src={data.img}
                                className="w-100"
                                alt="Blue Jeans Jacket"
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
    
                          <div className="col-lg-5 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                            <p>
                              <strong>{data.title}</strong>
                            </p>
    
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              className="btn btn-primary btn-sm me-1 mb-2"
                              data-mdb-toggle="tooltip"
                              title="Remove item"
                              onClick={() => dispatch(removeItem(data.id))}
                            >
                              <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
    
                          <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                            <div
                              className="d-flex mb-4"
                              style={{ maxWidth: "300px" }}
                            >
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-primary px-3 me-2"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  dispatch(decreaseItemQuantity(data.id))
                                }
                              >
                                <i className="fas fa-minus"></i>
                              </button>
    
                              <div className="form-outline">
                                <input
                                  id="form1"
                                  min="0"
                                  name="quantity"
                                  value={data.quantity}
                                  type="number"
                                  className="form-control"
                                  onChange={() => null}
                                />
                                <label className="form-label" for="form1">
                                  Quantity
                                </label>
                              </div>
    
                              <button
                                className="btn btn-primary px-3 ms-2"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  dispatch(increaseItemQuantity(data.id))
                                }
                              >
                                <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
                              </button>
                            </div>
    
                            <p className="text-start text-md-center">
                              <strong>{data.price}</strong>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                          <hr className="my-4" />
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                  <div className="card mb-4">
                    <div className="card-header py-3">
                      <h5 className="mb-0">Summary</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-0 px-0 pb-0">
                          Total Quantity
                          <span>{totalQuantity}</span>
                        </li>
    
                        <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-0 px-0 mb-3">
                          <div>
                            <strong>Total amount</strong>
                          </div>
                          <span>
                            <strong>{totalPrice}</strong>
                          </span>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
    
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
                      >
                        Go to checkout
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default CartPage;

    ProductCard.js
    import React from "react";
    import {
      MDBCard,
      MDBCardBody,
      MDBCardTitle,
      MDBCardText,
      MDBCardImage,
      MDBBtn,
      MDBContainer,
      MDBRow,
      MDBCol,
    } from "mdb-react-ui-kit";
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { addToCart } from "../features/cartSlice";
    
    export default function App() {
    
      const items = useSelector((state) => state.allCart.items);
      
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      return (
        <div className="m-2">
          <MDBContainer>
            <MDBRow className="mb-3">
              {items.map((item) => (
                <MDBCol key={item.id} size="md">
                  <MDBCard>
                    <MDBCardImage src={item.img} position="top" alt="..." />
                    <MDBCardBody>
                      <MDBCardTitle>{item.title}</MDBCardTitle>
                      <MDBCardText>{item.price}</MDBCardText>
                      <MDBBtn onClick={() => dispatch(addToCart(item))}>
                        Add to Cart
                      </MDBBtn>
                    </MDBCardBody>
                  </MDBCard>
                </MDBCol>
              ))}
            </MDBRow>
          </MDBContainer>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I hope it will help you